# Emulate a block device in a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, grep, containers

I'm currently trying to build a docker testing environment for a little tool I made.
Basically this tool uses `lsblk` to list block devices and `grep -a -b` to search for a string in a whole partition.

But now, I'm not sure how to create a testing env for that.
I know about Docker volumes, but it seems that using `-v myvolume:/myvolume` will only "duplicate" it as a directory.
I could also mount something on the base system, outside of my container, but **I need to avoid root privileges**.

Do you have any idea how I could proceed? Maybe the solution has more to do with core Linux tools than Docker.
The goal is to have a directory/image/anything that would be treated as a block device inside my Docker container. That is to say, ideally visible using `lsblk` but most importantly compatible with `grep -a -b`.

Comment: Write a mock of `lsblk` instead

Comment: Docker doesn't simulate hardware devices in any form; a virtual-machine setup might work better for you.